# How to Make a Portion of a Bold TOC Entry Not Bold on an Ad Hoc Basis

Tags: bold, tocloft, customize

Consider the code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\small\bfseries} 

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{INTRODUCTION (Unbold portion)}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

QUESTION: How may I make a portion of a bold-by-default TOC entry---not bold on an ad hoc basis? In this case, I would like to make **(Unbold portion)** to appear not bold.

Thank you.

Comment: Try `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{INTRODUCTION \normalfont (Unbold portion)}`  (delete previous .toc)

Comment: @SimonDispa Many thanks. That does the trick.

Comment: Just to be sure that `\normalfont` doesn't leak I'd contain it with a group like this: `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{INTRODUCTION {\normalfont (Unbold portion)}}`.

Comment: @Skillmon Many thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @SimonDispa You should make than an answer.

Comment: @SimonDispa I agree with Andrew Swann.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\normalfont` to switch to non-bold text. Since it will affect all subsequent text in the ToC line, it may be convenient, if necessary, to limit its scope with braces.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\small\bfseries} 

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{INTRODUCTION {\normalfont (Unbold portion)}  bolded text again}% changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you Simon Dispa.